# C4510RE terminated abnormally

Tags: switch, cisco-catalyst, cisco-4500

Hi I am unboxing 2x cartons of C4510RE chassis and find this booting up fault consistently appearing in both chassis.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Please find below logs:

```
Cisco IOS Software, IOS-XE Software, Catalyst 4500 L3 Switch  Software (cat4500es8-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 03.08.04.E RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2017 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Thu 06-Apr-17 08:19 by prod_rel_team

Cisco IOS-XE software, Copyright (c) 2005-2015 by cisco Systems, Inc.
All rights reserved.  Certain components of Cisco IOS-XE software are
licensed under the GNU General Public License ("GPL") Version 2.0.  The
software code licensed under GPL Version 2.0 is free software that comes
with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  You can redistribute and/or modify such
GPL code under the terms of GPL Version 2.0.
() For more details, see the
documentation or "License Notice" file accompanying the IOS-XE software,
or the applicable URL provided on the flyer accompanying the IOS-XE
software.




This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United
States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and
use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply
third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption.
Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for
compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you
agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable
to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at:


If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to
export@cisco.com.



Exception to IOS Thread:
Frame pointer 4D7E3718, PC = 27C4302C

IOSD-EXT-SIGNAL: Segmentation fault(11), Process = Init
-Traceback= 1#dd41163b8b17690ed69ab02c775ba4e8  :1FFA4000+7C9F02C :1FFA4000+156C390 :1FFA4000+7C97500 :1FFA4000+5B6E6D4 :1FFA4000+5B2C710 :1FFA4000+14DE3AC :1FFA4000+14DEA74 :1FFA4000+5BFBAFC :1FFA4000+5BFBF8C :1FFA4000+5C00AB0 :1FFA4000+13FFDB8 :1FFA4000+1400CE0 :1FFA4000+1EFEC1C :1FFA4000+194619C :1FFA4000+1EF8AD4 :1FFA4000+1EEDB18 

Fastpath Thread backtrace: 
-Traceback= 1#dd41163b8b17690ed69ab02c775ba4e8  pthread:188DA000+F9BC pthread:188DA000+91DC pthread:188DA000+91DC c:1A35E000+F6454 iosd_unix:1A743000+26C20 iosd_unix:1A743000+1D4F0 :1FFA4000+2593AD4 iosd_unix:1A743000+1BAD4 pthread:188DA000+6450 

CMI Thread backtrace: 
-Traceback= 1#dumount: /icstmpfs: not mounted
umount: /bootflash-ics: not mounted

<Thu Oct 12 21:19:01 2017> Message from sysmgr: Reason Code:[2] Reset Reason:Service [iosd] pid:[5813] terminated abnormally [11]. 
Details:
--------
Service: IOSd service
Description: IOS daemon
Executable: /tmp/sw/mount/cat4500es8-universalk9.SPA.152-4.E4.pkg//usr/binos/bin/iosd

Started at Thu Oct 12 21:16:28 2017 (710448 us)
Stopped at Thu Oct 12 21:19:01 2017 (845358 us)
Uptime: 2 minutes 33 seconds

Start type: SRV_OPTION_RESTART_STATELESS (23)
Death reason: SYSMGR_DEATH_REASON_FAILURE_SIGNAL (2)
Last heartbeat 0.00 secs ago

PID: 5813 
Exit code: signal 11 

CWD: /var/sysmgr/work


PID: 5813
UUID: 512
```

Comment: Which chassis specifically? I know of a WS-C4510R-E and a WS-C4510R+E, but not a WS-C4510RE. Also, which supervisor(s) and in which slots are the supervisors installed? Are you trying to boot the image that came on the supervisors, or have you replaced it?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug. Get tech support.

In the meantime you can try and narrow down the problem by restarting your switches with the smallest possible hardware and software configuration and see what triggers the problem.

(1) Hardware: 4510RE is a dual-supervisor chassis with line cards. So, pull out all the line cards, pull out the redundant power supply, pull out the redundant supervisor, and start with just the one supervisor and see if the abnormal termination still happens. If it does, you really have no option other than to wait for support. If it boots fine, then you can try inserting all the removed components one-by-one.

(2) Software: Sometimes abnormal terminations can happen when there is something in the startup-configuration that the software does not "digest" properly. Cisco provides a way to boot the device by not reading the startup-configuration (this is actually a part of the password recovery process) - you can try this process and see if there is something in the startup-configuration that is causing the problem.

To reiterate: the above is just a stopgap arrangement until your tech support finds the problem. My personal opinion is that is is better to just wait for support.

Comment: Thank you @mere3ortal , i will try your recommended steps and update you on my findings

Comment: It works . The booting works after i go into rommon and ignore the startup config through a series of confreg y/n qns

Comment: OK, but you've just worked around the problem. Once you configure your switch to do something useful (like, you know, switch packets :-)), it's possible the problem may come back - but at least now you'll know what line of configuration is causing the problem.

Comment: The issue reappear after I insert 6 line cards , I further isolate the issue by inserting the line cards 1 by 1 and booting up 1 increment at a time and discover faulty line card at slot 7 and replaced it with working 1. Now it’s fine.